# calling method in java doesn't work

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, methods

the method i’m try To call is the encrypt method it's from this class
but when i try to call it in call class it shows error in the method name it shows that the method is not there or not found :( please help me

```
package test;
public class MARS {
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] in,byte[] key){
            K = expandKey(key);
            int lenght=0;
            byte[] padding = new byte[1];
            int i;
            lenght = 16 - in.length % 16;
            padding = new byte[lenght];
            padding[0] = (byte) 0x80;

            for (i = 1; i < lenght; i++)
                    padding[i] = 0;

            byte[] tmp = new byte[in.length + lenght];
            byte[] bloc = new byte[16];

            int count = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < in.length + lenght; i++) {
                    if (i > 0 && i % 16 == 0) {
                            bloc = encryptBloc(bloc);
                            System.arraycopy(bloc, 0, tmp, i - 16, bloc.length);
                    }
                    if (i < in.length)
                            bloc[i % 16] = in[i];
                    else{
                            bloc[i % 16] = padding[count % 16];
                            count++;
                    }
            }
            if(bloc.length == 16){
                    bloc = encryptBloc(bloc);
                    System.arraycopy(bloc, 0, tmp, i - 16, bloc.length);
            }

            return tmp;
    }
```

}

This is the calling class the error shown in line 3

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[ ] array = “going to encrypt ”.getByte( );
    byte[ ] arrayEnc = MARS.encrypt(array);
    System.out.println(“plain text: ” + array);
    System.out.println(“Encrypted Text: ”+ arrayEnc);

}
```

Comment: There is no `encrypt` method taking one argument

Comment: see this lines .. **1) bloc = encryptBloc(bloc);** no method . **2) K = expandKey(key)**  K is not variable.  **3) The method expandKey(byte[]) is undefined for the**

Comment: this is only part of the code. this is the method i'm trying to call can access the other methods which are encryptBloc(bloc); K = expandKey(key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encrypt you have defined takes in 2 parameters 
*public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] in,byte[] key)* 
But you are trying to call it with one *MARS.encrypt(array)*.

Comment: yeah I realized that later sorry. but I have no idea how to call the key parameter, i only called the data parameter. any help please?

Comment: You have to create a key object which is a byte array and pass it to the method.
MARS.encrypt(array, key)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error you're referring to is a compile-time error? The encrypt(..) function is defined as taking two byte array parameters: the source data and the encryption key. In your main(..) method, you're only passing in a single byte array, the source data. You also need to pass in an encryption key.

Comment: yeah I realized that later sorry. but I have no idea how to call the key parameter, i only called the data parameter. any help please?